# Mouse hover and mouse out hide dom element with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, hover, mouseevent

I want to hide an dom element when you hover it. I want to show the div thats underneath it.
The problem is that when the first element hides, jquery doesn't see the hover anymore and brings the hover div back. So the div gets toggled really fast.

I want the "front" when you the mouse is out the area of the divs.

```
<div  class="blockLong front" ></div>
<div  class="blockLong"></div>
```

The divs are placed over eatchother with a absolute position and are the same size

This is the jquery:

```
$('.front').hover( function()
{
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.front').mouseout( function()
{
    $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: animate the opacity to 0 instead.

Comment: i want to hide it completely, not the opacity to 0

Comment: why the -1, whats wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1):

For consistency, you should use `hover` exclusively:

```
$('.front').hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo(500,0);
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500,1);
});
```

What this effectively does is add a handler for each of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

If you don't want the div to return when you the `mouseleave` event has fired, you could try this:

```
$('.front').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
});

$('blockLong:not(.front)').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.front').fadeIn(500);
})
```

Comment: i want to hide it completely, not the opacity to 0

Comment: @user1386906 When you set the opacity to 0, it *is* completely invisible.

Comment: yes its invisible, but when i have links in the divs underneath the i can't click them

Comment: @user1386906 Well you can't have it both ways. If you want to expose the underlying div to mouse events the mouseleave event *has* to fire first. If you don't want this to happen, use the second example I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div  class="blockLong front"></div>
<div  class="blockLong back"></div>
```

JS

```
$('.front').hover( function()
{
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.back').mouseout( function()
{
    $(".blockLong.front").show();
});
```

Comment: thx for your anwser, but i have many of these blocks. I found a anwser myself

Comment: @user1386906 In the future be sure to explain your questions more thoroughly.

Answer (score -1):

This is what i did:

```
<div  class="blockLong back"></div>
<div  class="blockLong front"></div>


$('.front').hover( function()
{
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.back').mouseout( function()
{
    $(this).next().show();
});
```